# Get value for user selected combination, from product combination array

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, prestashop-1.7

I need to get the EAN13 code for the combination that the user selects on the product page.

I generated a PS module and hooked it to hookdisplayProductAdditionalInfo. 
In the module PHP file, I can only get an array with EAN13 codes for all the product combinations.

```
$product = new Product((int)Tools::getValue('id_product'));
$id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
$combinations = $product->getAttributeCombinations((int)$id_lang, true);
  foreach ($combinations as $c) 
  {
    printf ($c['ean13']);
  }
```

The code above prints all the EAN13 codes. I need to get only the EAN13 for the combination that the user selected/is seeing. 
Every time the user changes the combination, I need to refresh and get the current EAN13.

The reason is that I'm sending the product code through API to an external server in order to get warehouses stocks and display on the screen.

Comment: what do you mean get it? you want to send it to the database? or what needs to happen with the code?

Comment: Yes, I need to store ean13 into a variable and use it in a API call. This would show the real stock at the moment in the warehouses. Every time a user clicks on a new attribute, I need to refresh the script and show the stock for the new ean13 combination code. I have a different ean13 code for each product combination, each one with different stocks of course.

Comment: ok then you should create a session for the user, and every time it is changed(refreshed) , you just update the session with the new one and use that when needed